# Array used for animation not releasing images. Memory Pressure

Tags: ios, arrays, memory, instruments, pressure

I have 5 arrays which I am using to load and play 5 sets of images to form 5 different animations.

I am having massive memory issues. Up to 500mb. The images only total around 15mb in size outside the app when I check their size in finder.

I ran the memory instrument whilst my app was running;

![MEMORY Status after the 5 arrays have been loaded.][1]

This image shows the memory after the five arrays have been loaded.
It seems pretty obvious that it is retaining the images after the arrays have ran?
Or at least I think that is the problem.

This is the code I have used for each array;

```
//Play Button 1 Animation

NSMutableArray *play1Frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0000"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0001"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0002"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0003"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0004"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0005"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0006"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0007"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0008"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0009"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0010"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0011"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0012"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0013"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0014"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0015"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0016"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0017"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0018"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0019"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0020"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0021"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0022"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0023"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0024"] ofType:@"png"]],
               [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"play_button0025"] ofType:@"png"]],
               nil];
play1Image.animationImages = play1Frames;
play1Image.animationDuration = 3;
play1Image.animationRepeatCount = 1;
play1Frames = nil;
```

I want to use this code for animation, I have tried this code;

```
UIImage* animatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"Anim" duration:20];
```

But it does not give me the functionality I want, also the memory issue was still present even with this code ^

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be, or if I have correctly identified the problem, can anyone help me fix it please?

Thank you.

Comment: Rob, it's time to learn Objective C. Your edit here displays a fundamental lack of knowledge in basic concepts.

Comment: Haha Leo, you are correct sir, how can I learn other than doing? If you could recommend any books etc I would be very grateful. I have struggled through and done quite a few good things with some other apps. But you are correct, my fundamentals are no where to be seen and I actively trying to learn them.

Comment: Also, at the end of the day I'm a front end designer before anything else, I would just like to see my animations in an app. Sorry Leo if you feel I am wasting your time.

Comment: Also I know that I have not filled the information in the NSMutable array code correctly, I left it as the answer showed so that I didn't complicate things. I am unsure why the first array has the error as I used the code exactly as the answer below stated.

Comment: I suggest the Stanford lectures.

Comment: I think you are also not trying or now wanting to try. I mean, have you actually looked at the error? Have you not seen the little arrow, showing you the exact problem? I think you have come here, looking for people to solve everything for you. It's not just the lack of knowledge; I think there is a lack of trying too.

Comment: Leo, I swear, I am trying, I stay up very late most nights when I have to be up early the next day trying to fix my code and work through it. I'm very new to this and I don't have any fundamentals. The little arrow doesn't mean to me what it does to you. I am sorry to have made you so angry that you feel you have to attack me like this. I can promise you I am really trying. There are many pieces of code I have successfully implemented without help, you only see my questions, and I have asked a lot so I see how it looks. Please Leo, just be patient with me.

Comment: I am trying with this more than anything else in my life right now. I am attempting to teach it to myself through questions and through literature on the web, but it is quite a hard subject to get in to for me.

Comment: Rob, I am not angry. If you remember we discussed yesterday and I tried to help you for a long time. I just fear you will not get the best help here until you cover the basics. :)

Comment: For example, in the screenshot above, you have several issues. One is, you put a DOT instead of a COMMA in the array. That's why it's red. You are also calling array methods on string literals, instead of using the array you build in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Leo, it's good to know you're not angry. You were extremely helpful yesterday. Please believe me when I say I am trying? I'm just very new to this, I am a front end designer, I just want to see my creations, my animations on an app.

Comment: Rob, please see my second comment regarding issues above.

Comment: AHHH! THE DOT! To be fair to me that dot was hard to see between all that Red.

Comment: Thank you Leo! All of my errors are now fixed and I learned something! Sorry if this isn't the best way to learn. I will get straight to the Stanford Lectures. Thanks for understanding and despite everything helping me anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43715/discussion-between-rob-swish-and-leo-natan)

Answer (score 1):

try this one,it's working proper and not getting any memory issue also:

```
// Load images
NSArray *imageNames = @[@"play_button0000.png", @"play_button0001.png", @"play_button0002.png", @"play_button0003.png",@"play_button0004.png", @"play_button0005.png", @"play_button0006.png", @"play_button0007.png",@"play_button0008.png", @"play_button0009.png", @"play_button0010.png", @"play_button0011.png",@"play_button0012.png", @"play_button0013.png", @"play_button0014.png",
                        @"play_button0015.png",@"play_button0016.png", @"play_button0017.png", @"play_button0018.png", @"play_button0019.png",@"play_button0020.png", @"play_button0021.png", @"play_button0022.png", @"play_button0023.png",@"play_button0024.png",
                        @"play_button0025.png"];
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];

}
 // Normal Animation
animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 3;
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:animationImageView];
```

may be it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm sorry but this did not fix my memory issue. It works fine for playing my animation but the memory goes right up and does not come back down again. I think the array is still not being released?

Comment: @RobSwish it working good in my application , can you show me more detail so get more idea about it?

Comment: Sure, should we go into chat?

Comment: ya sure.invite me whenever you want.

Comment: @DivyeshDobariya ya sure ...can you tell what is problem you facing?

Comment: I make an app to create video using array of images .When I create video at that time the memory increase and my app terminated.I think the problem is in the buffer .I will send my code to you .. please help me....

Comment: My code is here... https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbovsf0e7x3izq6/VideoMaker%205_new_16%203.zip?dl=0

Comment: dropbox is band here.please share other way like googledrive or other.

Comment: too mush work,so late rply , any way in page controller(how to used) you getting warning or other screen?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania I have also memory issue. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this: copy images to the bundle like this:

```
NSMutableArray *images=[[NSMutableArray   
alloc]initwithobjects:@"play_button0000.png",@"xxx.png",,,nil];
```

And write your animation code. The problem seems to be where you are adding the images to the array.

Just give a try.